# Android DatePicker pick wrong date

Tags: android

i got some strange problem in my android app, when i pick date for ex, 15march2013 in datepicker i get 9october2007

here's fragment from sorces

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (OnDateSetListener)getActivity(), year, month, day);
    }

}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    d.setDate(day);
    d.setMonth(month);
    d.setYear(year);
    int flags = 0;
    flags |= DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE;
    flags |= DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR;
    String str = DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, d.getTime(), flags);
    date.setText(str);
}
```

actually i ran out of idea what can be wrong
pls help!

Comment: Where have you defined the d object?

Comment: DatePickerFragment is nested class, so d object is defined in "main" class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These calls are deprecated:

```
  d.setDate(day);
  d.setMonth(month);
  d.setYear(year);
```

And are not doing what you suppose.  If you trace through and watch d change with each call,  you will be surprised to see it just adding those amounts to itself.

You should instead do something like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day);

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d yyyy MMM");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
date.setText(str);
```

You can see more date formatting options here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks HaIR, Calendar was exactly this what i needed to fix it

Answer (score -1):

The way in which i am achieving this:

```
    public class AddEditCourseActivity extends Activity {
              private Button classStartBT;
        private DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog;
        private Calendar classStartDate;
        private SimpleDateFormat mDateFormatter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                classStartDate = new GregorianCalendar();

                /** Initialize the mTimeFormatter object */
                mTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy dd, MM");

                classStartBT = (Button) findViewById(R.id.courseClassStartBT);

    classStartBT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                                MyActivity.this, mDateSetListener,
                                classStartDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                classStartDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                                classStartDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));



                    mDatePickerDialog.show();

                } // end onClick
            });

        }


    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
int dayOfMonth) {


                    classStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    classStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                    /**
                     * display the "class start time" on the buttons
                     */


    classStartBT.setText(mDateFormatter.format(classStartTime.getTime()));

            }
        };

    } // end activity
```